# MVCScaffolding for MVC4?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

In the past, I had some success in automation of coding with customization functionality of MVCScaffolding for my MVC sites. Now, with great knockout.js and other js libraries, I want to automate javascript coding as well. Is MVCScaffolding still working for MVC4? Before getting into it, I would like to check with experienced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using MVC 4 RC and scaffolding is working great.

Comment: That's exactly the answer I was looking for. Thanks! As soon as I can mark it as answer....

Answer (score 2):

It currently works great on non-Windows 8 machines.  However, it does not support the version of powershell that ships with Windows 8.  Hopefully a fix is coming soon.

[You can review the most recent changesets on codeplex.](http://mvcscaffolding.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets)

EDIT: As of October 25th 2012 it is now fixed!